# Apple Mobile Web App CSS Issue

Tags: jquery, web-applications

I currently have a website that I am trying to use as a web app.

I've added the approiate meta tag, `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` which works as advertised.

The only issue is that when you launch the website as a web app, some of the CSS in a jQuery timer I have doesn't display correctly. The numbers load with no color, and once they start rotating, that's when the correct color shows up. You can see this from the screenshot.

Any ideas on why this is happening? This only happens when you launch it as a web app.

Here is a demo, http://jako.in/countdown/

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Maybe your CSS is being cached. Perhaps adding ?randomNumber(); at the end of your url will force a new style sheet.

Comment: It would help if you have some code for people to look at.

Comment: @Steven Doing so now. Just updated my question with a link to my example.

Comment: I am seeing all your numbers as white. Tried on chrome desktop, safari on ipad and chrome on ipad. Not exactly your colour preference, but it seem consistent.

Comment: @Steven, it only happened when you added it to your homescreen and then launched it as a web app. I've provided an answer below as I found out what was causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up finding the solution to this. Turning on apple-mobile-web-app-capable was causing Safari to treat that timer as a phone number. Which is why it was turning it another color. Adding `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />` fixed my issue.